# PHP: SQL from two queries - ignore duplicates

Tags: php, sql, duplicates

So I have this piece of code. It retreives a list of rooms from the table "rom" and is then supposed to check this against the same rooms in "booket". How can I just print out the rooms that are NOT in booket in the set time.

"Rom"-database looks like this:

```
romnavn   | romtype (not relevant here)

ex: 81-77 | 2
```

"Booket" looks like:

```
romnavn   | bruker      | dato       | fra | til

ex: 81-77 | foo@bar.net | 03.04.2013 | 16  | 18
```

(this means that the room will be booked from 16:00:00 to 18:00:00)

If the room shows up in both queries it should be ignored.

My guess was two while-loops, "`$notFreeA`" inside the first one, but I'm not getting the result I want.

I'm fairly sure that both the DB and queries are, well..,bad, but any help would be very much appreciated :)

```
require "sql/sqlConnect.php";
require "functions/functions.php";
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');
$time = date('H:i:s');
$date = date('d.m.Y');
$nearestHour = roundToNearestHour($time);

$allRooms = "SELECT * FROM rom";
$notFree = "SELECT * FROM booket WHERE dato='$date' AND fra<='$nearestHour';";

$allRoomA = mysql_query($allRooms);
$notFreeA = mysql_query($notFree);
```

The function to round up/down to nearest room looks like this:

```
function roundToNearestHour($time) {
$part = explode(":", $time);

if(count($part) != 3)
  return 0;

if($part[2] > 30)
  $parts[1]++;

if($part[1] > 30)
  $part[0]++;

return $part[0];
}
```

Comment: `date('d.m.Y')` for use in-query? Why not use native mysql date/time fields? using custom date formats makes it near impossible for mysql to use any of its VERY USEFUL date/time functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this with one query:

```
select *
from room r
where r.romnavn not in (select roomnavn booket WHERE dato='$date' AND fra<='$nearestHour')
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need one query to do this. Any one of these three will produce the results you desire:

```
SELECT * FROM rom WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM booket WHERE dato='$date' AND fra<='$nearestHour'
   AND rom.romnavn = booklet.romnavn)

SELECT rom.* FROM rom LEFT OUTER JOIN booket USING romnavn
   WHERE dato='$date' AND fra<='$nearestHour' AND booket.romnavn IS NULL

SELECT * FROM rom WHERE romnavn NOT IN
   (SELECT romnavn FROM booket WHERE dato='$date' AND fra<='$nearestHour')
```

That said, this table design is very poor. You don't appear to be using native datetime types, and your primary keys are poorly named and should be something easier to index (like integer ids).

If there's only one change you can make, you should at least ensure that the `dato` column is actually a DATE type and not a varchar. As it is, any date-based sorting or filtering will be extremely difficult to perform with SQL.